# Не вызывается onActivityResult()

Tags: java, android, activity

Во время закрытия активити не выполняется onActivityResult()

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Log.e("TAG","Работает");
  }
```

Так я запускаю следующе активити

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Cart_level_1.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivityForResult(intent,1);
```

Получаем результат

```
 if(!this.getClass().toString().equals("class ilhom4ik_app.com.girbar.main$1")) {
                            Intent results = new Intent();
                            results.putExtra("res","go");
                            setResult(RESULT_OK, null);
                            finish();
                        }
```

Но почему-то не запускается onActivityResult()

Comment: вместо `getApplicationContext()` передайте в `intent` `YourActivityName.this`

Comment: не работает данное решение (

Comment: Пока не очень понятно что у вас не работает, но есть пару моментов: почему в setResult(RESULT_OK, null); передаете null вместо вашего интента? Log.e - логирование ошибок, для дебага используйте Log.d. Хотя это и не имеет отношения к вашему вопросу.

Comment: Совет выше все-таки указан верно - не нужно передавать в интент контекст вашего приложения, а нужно передавать контекст активити. Замените на this или ActivityName.this. И вызов суперметода в onActivityResult не нужен.

Answer (score 2):

Возможно условие не верно или до этого кода выполнение вообще не доходит, но для этого случая Вы не сеттите никакого результата.
Результат нужно возвращать всегда. Для этого в `onCreate` запускаемой активности вызовите

```
    setResult(RESULT_CANCELED);
```

Теперь что бы не произошло вернётся результат "отменено".
При успешном выполнении задачи Вы переопределите его другим, нужным Вам результатом.